# Swift 2.2 - NSArray element failed to match Swift Array Element Type for cells in a TableViewController

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I am making a simple notes app and when starting the app it gives me the error, "NSArray element failed to match Swift Array Element Type". Though there are many other questions like this, none of them had the problem in a tableViewController when putting the

```
    cell.textLabel!.text = noteTitles[indexPath.row].title
```

Here is my full code and the class for the array:

Code:

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var noteTitles:[Note] = []

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, 
                            numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return noteTitles.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, 
        cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", 
            forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel!.text = noteTitles[indexPath.row].title // Error here.

        return cell
    }   
}
```

And the `Note` Class:

```
class Note {
    var title = ""
    var content = ""
}
```

Please help me and tell me what I am doing wrong and help me fix it. Thank you in advance!

Here is image as asked of NSCoding error:

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPWws.png)

Here is image of KeyedUnarchiver error:

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wmz3N.png)

Comment: Can you add the `Note` class implementation as well?

Comment: @Mark Sorry, I forgot to add, just added it.

Comment: How are you loading the values into the array of `Note`s ?  The error message says that the array doesn't have `Note` objects in it.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is you changed the `Note` class, and you're trying to load the old class from `NSUserDefaults`. What happens if you clear out `NSUserDefaults` first? (Either by changing the key you're using, or adding in a hard coded `removeObjectForKey()`.

Comment: I changed the key, but now it won't save. How would it save now. I just added an "s" to the key "note"

Comment: What do you mean it won't save? Assuming you changed the key everywhere (you should really store the key in a constant), it should save and load the same as before.

Comment: It's tough to tell what's wrong with your saving and loading from `NSUserDefaults`. (This article might help you: http://nshipster.com/nscoding/). If you're still having trouble with it, open another question about that issue specifically. As for the constant, I mean add a constant property (`private let noteKey = "notes"`) to your file, and use that constant instead of the string literal. That way, when you change the key, you only need to change it in one spot.

Answer (score 0):

array and dictionary for NSUserDefaults must have property list elements. so using custom objects for NSUserDefaults normally impossible.

you must use NSCoding, and NSKeyed(Un)Archiver for changed to NSData from array

How is this?

see here [Encoding and Decoding Objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Articles/codingobjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000948-BCIHBJDE)

```
// just examples
class Note: NSObject, NSCoding {
    var note: String = ""
// you must overriding init?(coder: NSCoder) and func encode(with: NSCoder)
    // for unarchiving from NSData
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init()
        self.note = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("note")// just example
    }
    // for archiving to NSData
    func encode(coder aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encodeObject(self.note, forKey: "note")
    }
}
```

set note titles (sorry for swift 3 statement. you can find right code with autocompletion)

```
let notesArchived = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: notes), forKey: "notes") // is NSData
// save notesArchived to NSUserDefaults
```

get note titles

```
let notesData = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "notes")! // NSData
let notes = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: notesData)
```

this possible to me

Comment: For the set note titles and get note titles, would they be in the Note class or in the ViewController?

Comment: I think more comfortable that be in viewcontroller

Comment: When I add the NSCoding to the class, it gives me an error, Type 'Note' does not confirm to protocol 'NSCoding'. What do I do?

Comment: and continuously exist error on set cell's text line, can you post error captured image?

Comment: yeah, firstly, you should have understand [Encoding and Decoding Objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Articles/codingobjects.html)

Comment: Encoding and Decoding objects is written in objective-c. I can't understand it. I did post the pictures

Comment: The pictures appear after the link "code" is clicked

Comment: sorry i'm asking for (_cell.textLabel!.text = noteTitles[indexPath.row].title // Error here._)

Comment: oh, that's good. and why use NSUserDefaults anyway. it's good for some flags. but containing for custom objects is uneasy. i suggest database like core data or Realm.

Comment: Now it shows a different error, "Type 'Note' does not conform to protocol 'NSCoder'". And at both of the self.note it shows "Value of type 'Note' has no member 'note'" What is problem?

Comment: unarchiving from value of NSData(from NSUserDefaults). not Note type. archiving too.

Comment: sorry, may be make some misunderstand, archiving is NSData from archivable objects. here now array of Note @EpicGamer_1

Comment: How would I set this up using CoreData?

Comment: I have it in the project, so what would I do?

Comment: forget core data. may be Realm more fit @EpicGamer_1. and Realm? realm.io is everything. just look.

Comment: I have never used realm, what do I have to do to implement and save. Could you post how it would work?

Comment: umm, it's so hard to let know what to post just once. CoreData or Realm, and sqlite, etc... is database. How much do you know about database. may be you should research database first. and search realm.io from google.

Comment: I have added realm framework and it is working fine, what code do I need to add the array noteTitles, which is an array of class Note to realm and save it and get the data from it everytime? Please help